# In an Array, if there is a list of numbers, how would I return the point a number stops increasing and begins decreasing, and vice versa?

Tags: python

How can I find the index at which a number stops increasing and begins decreasing?

For example: arr = [1,2,3,5,4,3,1]. I need to return the number 3.
another example: arr =[4,5,6,8,6,4] I need to return the number 4.

Comment: Show what your best shot

Comment: `arr.index(max(arr))`?  Not sure if you need to account for multiple local maxima, but if the values simply go up and then down, there's only one maximum (the absolute maximum) which makes it pretty easy.

Comment: I think you should give more examples. What should `1,4,2,6,3,10,7,8` return?

Comment: @OneCricketeer that should return 6.

Comment: Even though "point when increase stops and then decreases" includes values 4,6, and 10? What about `1,2,3,10,10`? Or an array of only increasing numbers?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.